# Algolia Ipaddress based geolocation search

Tags: algolia

In Algolia aroundLatLong, Is it possible to manually pass the ipaddress and make the method "aroundLatLongViaIP" work? Now it seems that it will auto-detect based on the request ipaddress.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you just need to add the following custom HTTP header `X-Forwarded-For` => `END_USER_IP` with your geo-based search query.